# Android System Update Spyware Can Steal Your Photos, Money, Record Calls and Track You Too. What to do if this happens?

Tags: malware, android, smartphone, spyware

I came across [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.news18.com/amp/news/tech/android-system-update-spyware-can-steal-your-photos-money-record-calls-and-track-you-too-3603692.html) website and suddenly I got worried.

What worries me is apart from the system update threat mentioned I have been visiting so many sites, clicked on pop-ups, downloaded apps from third-party stores etc. I don't know if there is any spyware or virus in my phone but it worries me now.

What if my personal data, personal photos are already there somewhere on some remote server? If this happens, if i see my photos in the internet that i never uploaded never even backed up in cloud storage what should i do then? Has this kind of things ever happened? What kind of data can they steal or copy from my phone passwords, bank accounts, photos or even videos?

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions

Comment: If you have been the victim of a crime, you need to report it to the police or the law enforcement body in your area that deals with cyber crime. Aside from that, this is not a security question. Your other questions are answered by the link you provided.